# How to properly format code in a GitHub comment

Tags: github

I'm having an hard time trying to insert code in a GitHub comment.

This:

[image]

becomes this:

[image]

and this:

[image]

becomes this:

[image]

I'm astonished to have such a problems in a website specialized in collaborating (thus discussing) on programming code.

What's the solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You keep trying to use single-line (also known as inline) markdown code syntax:

```
my code is `print("hello, world")`
```

While you should be using the multi-line variant:

````
    my code is:
    ```
    def foo():
        print("hello, world")
    ```
````

Read up about Markdown [here](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet).

Comment: Ah thanks! on the toolbar there's only the first type, called "Add code, <Ctrl+e>"